# Bulk save attachments, except pictures, from multiple emails

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I was using code to download attachments from multiple Outlook emails at once.

I applied the code in my new job's Outlook. It downloads all the items in the body of the emails including pictures.

I only wish to download files included as attachments, which are usually .pdf files.

Maybe restricting the code to download PDFs would work.

```vb
Public Sub SaveA()
    'Update 20200821
    Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim xSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xAttCount As Long
    Dim xFilePath As String, xFolderPath As String, xSaveFiles As String
    Dim xYesNo As Integer
    Dim xFlag As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    xFolderPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
    Set xSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    xFolderPath = xFolderPath & "\Attachments\"
    If VBA.Dir(xFolderPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        VBA.MkDir xFolderPath
    End If
    For Each xMailItem In xSelection
        Set xAttachments = xMailItem.Attachments
        xAttCount = xAttachments.Count
        xSaveFiles = ""
        If xAttCount > 0 Then
            For i = xAttCount To 1 Step -1
                xFilePath = xFolderPath & xAttachments.Item(i).FileName
                xFlag = True
                If VBA.Dir(xFilePath, 16) <> Empty Then
                    xYesNo = MsgBox("The file is exists, do you want to replace it", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Kutools for Outlook")
                    If xYesNo = vbNo Then xFlag = False
                End If
                If xFlag = True Then
                    xAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile xFilePath
                    If xMailItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                        xSaveFiles = xSaveFiles & vbCrLf & "<Error! Hyperlink reference not valid.>"
                    Else
                        xSaveFiles = xSaveFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & xFilePath & "'>" & xFilePath & "</a>"
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            If xSaveFiles <> "" Then
                If xMailItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                    xMailItem.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & xSaveFiles & vbCrLf & xMailItem.Body
                Else
                    xMailItem.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & xSaveFiles & "</p>" & xMailItem.HTMLBody
                End If
            End If
            xMailItem.Save
        End If
    Next
    Set xAttachments = Nothing
    Set xMailItem = Nothing
    Set xSelection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Many similar questions already on this site, should be helpful: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+outlook+save+pdf+attachments+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: `If LCase(xAttachments.Item(i).FileName) Like "*.pdf" Then`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `HTMLBody` property and see if any attachments are actually referenced by the `<img>` tags. The value used for the `<img>` tags can be set in the MIME content id (`PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID`). So, first you retrieve the content ID and then search for the value in the message body. For example:

```
Function CountVisibleAttachment(ByVal m As MailItem) As Integer
    Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
    Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

    Dim a As Attachment
    Dim pa As propertyAccessor
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim cid As String

    Dim body As String

    c = 0

    body = m.HTMLBody

    For Each a In m.Attachments
        Set pa = a.propertyAccessor
        cid = pa.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID)

        If Len(cid) > 0 Then
            If InStr(body, cid) Then
            emb = emb + 1
            Else
                'In case that PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN does not exists,
                'an error will occur. We simply ignore this error and
                'treat it as false.
                On Error Resume Next
                If Not pa.GetProperty(PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN) Then
                    c = c + 1
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Else
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next a
    CountVisibleAttachment = c
End Function
```